# Variable export in node

Tags: node.js

I have a config file with this code:

```
const email =  {
  persistentUserModel: Users,
  expirationTime: 600, // 10 minutes

  verificationURL: 'http://localhost:8000/email-verification/${URL}',
  transportOptions: {
    service: 'Gmail',
    auth: {
      user: 'my@email.com',
      pass: 'myPassword'
    }
  },

  hashingFunction: myHasher,
  passwordFieldName: 'pw'
}

var configuration = Object.assign({
  host: process.env.HOST || 'localhost',
  port: process.env.PORT || 3000,
  databaseUrl: process.env.MONGO_URL || 'mongodb://localhost/cervezas',
  uploadsDir: path.join( __dirname, 'static', 'uploads' ),
  auth,
  email
}, environment)

module.exports = configuration
```

Eslint give me some errors:
- User is not defined
- myHasher is not defined

In another file is where I load this config file, and where I require the model and the function:

```
var myHaser= require('myHasher');
var Users = require('../models/Users')
....
nev.configure(configuration.email);
```

I don't want  to require the model and function in the config file as it's only a config file.

What is the proper way to do it?

Comment: How can you get this `user` value in config file `persistentUserModel: Users,`?

Answer (score 0):

here is my sample code that implement your requirement :

```
var serverConfig = {};


serverConfig.MySqlConfig = {
    MysqlUsername: "root",
    MySqlPassword: "",
    MySqlHost: "127.0.0.1",
    MySqlDbName: "Geomat"

};

serverConfig.ServerPort = {
    Administrator: 1234,
    Geomat: 8888,
    Bank: 1366
};


serverConfig.default =
{
    Debug: true
};

exports.serverConfig = serverConfig;
```

and require inside your main program like this:

```
var serverConfig = require('./serverConfig').serverConfig;
```

and usage :

```
this.io = require('socket.io').listen(serverConfig.ServerPort.Geomat);
```

some note about your code :

- you use **const** that is just allowed in **strict mode** or **ES6**
- you assign a object value that dose not exist/implement in your presented config file

> persistentUserModel: Users,

Comment: yes, I'm using babel for transpiling code. The question is how I can defined the persistentUserModel or my hashingFunction without implementing it in the conf file?

Comment: you mean you have a dynamic parameter( or some thing like this )  in your config file?

Comment: Yes, a dynamic parameter.

Comment: So you should init it some where , its not possible, in a config file you have static value.
you can implement a simple function that throw an error to user to implement it if it's not exist , or implement your function in an other JS file and require it to your config file .